# Is the : (colon) and . (fullstop) a bit oversized in Courier font?

Tags: fonts

Today I came across a blog post on daring fireball about a new font: Courier Prime. From the [font preview](http://quoteunquoteapps.com/courierprime/#tabs-1), I found that the `:` and `.` are a bit oversized.

Then I checked the Courier font in Mac Font Book app. The `:` and `.` also appear oversized (including the fullstop beneath the `?` (question mark), comparing to the other characters.

Is it my eyes' problem or is there a story behind?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to back it up, but this is my guess: Courier's dots are four pixels -- two by two dots. One of the font's historical uses was on 80s dotmatrix printers. Were the font to have single-pixel dots, they would disappear if only one of the matrix's dots would malfunction or not display well due to ink shortage. Having four-pixel dots prevents that problem, in addition to helping legibility.

Besides that, the original analog Courier typeface [was made for typewriters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_%28typeface%29) and I suppose having a small period would have the typebars pierce the paper (and damage the machine) rather than leave ink on it.